# How to remove rows with special character at the end of string in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I want to remove rows if the column `'Submitter'` has special character `'X'` at the end of the string in dataframe.

```
 Submitter       Age     Country
 AfiqX           23      Malaysia
 Nur, AthirahX   23      Malaysia
 Nur, Alia       23      Malaysia
```

In the above example dataframe, I want to delete rows 1 & 2 as it contains 'X' at the end of the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use endswith of str(pandas series)

```
df = df[~df['Submitter'].str.endswith('X')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df[df['Submitter'].str.endswith("X") == False])
```

this will give all the rows which don't end with X